# Is there a simple way to insert text into each line of a table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters

I have a LaTeX document (memoir class) broken into unnamed, numbered chapters, like so `\chapter{}`.

I'd like the table of contents to look roughly like this:

```
Contents

Chapter 1 ............... 1

Chapter 2 ............... 5
```

However, `\tableofcontents` generates the following:

```
Contents

1 ............... 1

2 ............... 5
```

Is there a way to insert the word 'Chapter' into each line of the table of contents, preferably without naming the chapters and re-configuring the chapter titles?

I've done a fair amount of searching and have looked into `tocloft`, `titletoc` and other such packages, however I haven't found a solution to this particular problem.

I'm hoping I've missed something simple here.

Comment: In memoir, something like `\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}` is the basic idea (change the `\space` bit as needed).

Comment: @jon Can you please turn you comment into an answer?

Comment: If `babel` (or similar) is used, then @jons suggestion can be altered to `\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic mechanics for this are pretty simple.  If you're writing an English unilingual document with the `memoir` class, just add:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}
```

If you're not writing in English, as daleif says, you can use the `\chaptername` macro.  Say something like:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername\space}
```

A complete example, which lets you try both:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newif\ifusebabel % <-- a conditional just for trying both
%\usebabeltrue    % <-- uncomment if you want to see the change (but compile twice 
                  %     to get the change reflected in the ToC!)

\ifusebabel
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername\space}
\else
\renewcommand\cftchaptername{Chapter\space}
\fi

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{}
\chapter{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!  I'd hoped that this would be simpler than I was making it.

Comment: @palmee4 -- I know the feeling! Glad it works for you.